# JQuery validation plugin not working with JQuery version 1.11.2

Tags: jquery

I have a php project in which I was using `Jquery 1.11.2` to perform some tasks.Everything is working fine except when I included the jquery validation engine. 
My forms are not being validated and I think this is caused by conflicting Jquery versions ie version `1.11.2` which I was using in my project and version `1.6.0` which is included in the validation engine.

What can I do to get my forms to be validated?
Is there a validation engine version which is compatible with `Jquery 1.11.2`?

Comment: You can also support your post with code snippets having trouble with.

Comment: Have you considered upgrading that validation plugin as well?

Comment: I used the jquery migrate and form validation is perfectly ok. Problem is, on my form, I had an ajax code snippet which was fetching values from a database table and populating a select box depending on the option box selected. That piece of code stopped working.

Comment: I am wondering why the Ajax code stopped work while I have a similar code snippet on the same page where a textbox is getting its value from the database depending on the selection made from a drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery-migrate - https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate. This basically restores APIs and features removed as of version 1.9